# Strange +99 in @Order Spring

Tags: spring

Anyone can explain what is the reason for +99 in `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 99)` I've seen in some spring documentation?

`Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE` means that some interceptor will have the maximum priority in the chain executed by spring, but for spring, the lower the number the higher the priority. 
So if you look at `Ordered` class, you'll see

```
HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

Therefore adding `+99` will in fact DECREASE the priority.

What is the reason for this, so?

For example, in the end of the section:
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#websocket-stomp-authentication-token-based

Comment: Perhaps the first 99 priority values are reserved for some purpose?

Comment: @Carcigenicate yes, maybe.. no idea.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 99)` is `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 100)` in [AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/25feedb8701ddac92a239376ccbcf634f54707e2/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/socket/AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer.java). `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 99)` is only needed if you want to implement **authorization** described in the next [section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#websocket-stomp-authorization) of your link (So that the class with +99 do logic which is needed for authorization +100). Authorization will be done by extending `AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer` as [described](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.x/reference/html5/#websocket-authorization).